# How to get version of SharePoint installed?

Tags: sharepoint, version, sharepoint-2013

How can I get the version of SharePoint that is installed on my server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's crazy that there is no easy way to find out what Edition (SKU) of SharePoint 2013 are you running. To find out, you have to dig the registry:

- Open Regedit
- Navigate to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\15.0\WSS\InstalledProducts
- Compare the guids with these:

**C5D855EE-F32B-4A1C-97A8-F0A28CE02F9C**    --  **SharePoint Server 2013**

**CBF97833-C73A-4BAF-9ED3-D47B3CFF51BE**   --   **SharePoint Server 2013 Preview**

**B7D84C2B-0754-49E4-B7BE-7EE321DCE0A9**    --  **SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise**

**298A586A-E3C1-42F0-AFE0-4BCFDC2E7CD0**    --  **SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise Preview**

**D6B57A0D-AE69-4A3E-B031-1F993EE52EDC**    --  **Microsoft Office Web Apps Server 2013**

**9FF54EBC-8C12-47D7-854F-3865D4BE8118**    --  **SharePoint Foundation 2013**

**35466B1A-B17B-4DFB-A703-F74E2A1F5F5E**    --  **Project Server 2013**

**BC7BAF08-4D97-462C-8411-341052402E71**    --  **Project Server 2013 Preview**

**Reference :** http://www.thesysadminhimself.com/2013/01/identify-sharepoint-2013-foundation-or.html

**msdn Link :** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj659075.aspx

You can use powershell too

Open SharePoint Powershell with Run as administrator
Run this command:

```
get-spfarm | select BuildVersion
```

Thanks Naim Murati.

Comment: I do this but my number is `90150000-110D-0000-1000-0000000FF1CE` and your second link have a error . what is my share point version?

Answer (score 15):

Run this PowerShell script

```
get-spfarm | select BuildVersion
```

Answer (score 9):

If it's up and working, or just a webserver running SharePoint and you don't have access to console/admin/registry or s.th. else, just good ol' browser, you might add `_vti_pvt/service.cnf` after your base SharePoint-URL to determine the version number.

You'll get something like this:

```
vti_encoding:SR|utf8-xx
vti_extenderversion:SR|15.x.x.x
```

And Versionmapping... As far as I remember (please correct me if incorrect):

```
v12.x = SP2007/WSS
v14.x = SP2010
v15.x and higher = SP2013
```

Dunno the one for SP2007 anymore.

Just had to figure this out and found this answer is missing here, though you might (?) not be able to get more insight, just the general version (as said, please correct me if it's more specific, in the comments).

*Edit*: Here you can find the exact Version numbers from SP2007 to SP2013: http://blog.fpweb.net/what-sharepoint-version-am-i-using/#.VBlbNucv-9Y (you have to scroll a bit, just under the mid of the article).

Comment: This is the answer I needed, I don't have access to the server registry or anything like that.

Answer (score 4):

open SharePoint Management shell and type command

```
(Get-SPFarm).Products
```

you will get the GUIDs. Find your GUID from below list. That will be your installed SharePoint version

```
               GUID                              Product
35466B1A-B17B-4DFB-A703-F74E2A1F5F5E    Project Server 2013
BC7BAF08-4D97-462C-8411-341052402E71    Project Server 2013 Preview
C5D855EE-F32B-4A1C-97A8-F0A28CE02F9C    SharePoint Server 2013
CBF97833-C73A-4BAF-9ED3-D47B3CFF51BE    SharePoint Server 2013 Preview
B7D84C2B-0754-49E4-B7BE-7EE321DCE0A9    SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise
298A586A-E3C1-42F0-AFE0-4BCFDC2E7CD0    SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise Preview
D6B57A0D-AE69-4A3E-B031-1F993EE52EDC    Microsoft Office Web Apps Server 2013
9FF54EBC-8C12-47D7-854F-3865D4BE8118    SharePoint Foundation 2013
```