# Which sharepoint edition am I using?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

The title might mislead you to say that I have got to answer it but please read on :) . 
Using the [solution of SigarDave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511590/how-to-get-version-of-sharepoint-installed) I have found that **SharePoint Foundation 2013** and **SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise** are installed by our server admins in our 64bit sharepoint server. 
My questions are

1. Will both be used?
2. If not how do I find which one is being used?

Thanks for you help in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which one your web request is pointed to. I'm not sure if there are conflicts that would actually prevent both from being installed.

The fastest way I can suggest that you check is to simply go to your site's front end, click the gear in the upper right and select Site Contents > Add Subsite and under the Templates' publishing tab section, see if 'Enterprise Wiki' is an option. That is not a template that is active in Foundations.

You can also see which sites are active under IIS. If you don't have a need for it (not sure why you would), don't run Foundation on the same box as SharePoint server, it complicates things and weighs it down.